# Run Robot in Jenkinsfile does not fetch the correct test.robot file from Github

Tags: jenkins, testing, version-control, automated-tests, robotframework

So I have a school project that have given me so many headaches in every step of the way. It is located on Github and is run through Jenkins as a pipeline project, parameterized with git parameters for branches. There are 2 branches, main and b1 and this is my Jenkinsfile

```
pipeline {
    agent any
    stages { 
        stage('build'){
           steps{
               sh "mvn compile"
           }
        }
        stage('Test') {
            steps{
                sh "mvn test"
            }
            post {
                always {
                    jacoco(
                        execPattern: 'target/*.exec',
                        classPattern: 'target/classes',
                        sourcePattern: 'src/main/java',
                        exclusionPattern: 'src/test*'
                    )
                    junit '**/TEST*.xml'
                }
            }
        }
        stage('Run Robot and Post Test') {
            steps{
                sh script: 'python -m robot C:/Users/ersha/.jenkins/workspace/Pär_Ershag/Selenium/test.robot', returnStatus: true
            }
            post {
                always {
                    robot outputPath: 'C:/Users/ersha/.jenkins/workspace/Pär_Ershag@2', passThreshold: 100.0, unstableThreshold: 70.0, onlyCritical: false
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

My issue is that regardless of what branch I choose to build it will always use an old version of test.robot located at the same path as the step sh script: 'python -m robot...' is refering to. Main and b1 have both different versions of the file but neither are run. This despite having a "clean before cheackout" step in additional behaviours.

I have compared my Jenkinsfile to others doing the same project and the biggest difference is that the stage for 'Run Robot and Post Test' is stated as:
bat " robot *their test.robot path*"

I can't use bat for my steps for some reason even though I use windows hence why I had to use sh and a script in Jenkins to make it work.

ps: I'm kinda new to Jenkins so there are many things that I don't understand yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using hard coded paths is most of the times a bad idea.

Jenkins has a built in variable to reference the agent/node actual workspace. In you example I would try:

```
(...)
stage('Run Robot and Post Test') {
            steps{
                sh script: 'cd ${WORKSPACE} && python -m robot Pär_Ershag/Selenium/test.robot', returnStatus: true
            }
            post {
                always {
                    robot outputPath: '${WORKSPACE}/Pär_Ershag@2', passThreshold: 100.0, unstableThreshold: 70.0, onlyCritical: false
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: I tried this and it sort of worked. I had to also remove the PÄR_ERSHAG and PÄR_ERSHAG@2 parts for it to go all the way.
Thanks so much for the help

Comment: @PärErshag It is a good gesture to mark my answer as Accepted :)

Comment: Sorry. Forgot I could do that